# Redirect issue with login and paths

Tags: redirect, login, session

I'm gonna probably find another way around this, but I'm still very new to Craft and want to ask if I'm missing something obvious. This is a commerce site that needs a front-end login.

I have an `account` template folder with some templating that looks like this (it's an extended layout, leaving out unnecessary lines):

```
{# account/index.html #}
{% block main %}
    {% if craft.session.isLoggedIn %}
        {% include 'account/account.html' %}
    {% else %}
        {% include 'account/login_signup.html' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And an excerpt from my `general.php`

```
{# excerpt from my general.php file #}

'loginPath' => 'account',

'postLoginRedirect' => 'account',
```

When a logged-out user goes to `website.com/account` the `login_signup.html` page is spit out and a user can sign in (ignore the sign-up part). If they type in their info correctly, it leads to an `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` of `account` redirecting to `account`. This doesn't make sense to me, as both the login url and the post-login url point at the same path and load the same template, but the template should obviously handle the two situations differently. It should spit out the `account.html` template if the user is logged in, and if not, the `login_signup.html` template. These two template files have **nothing** in them right now, so it's not some other templating mistake.

If I remove either of the two config variables I presented in my `general.php` file, everything works but the routes I want aren't there.

I want a logged out user to visit `account`, get a sign in (`login_signup.html`) form they then use, and get redirected to `account` and the template will spit out the `account.html` template.

**Edit** Basically, if a user is logged in with my `general.php` having those two configs set to the same path (`account`), this always results in too many redirects:

```
{% block main %}
    {% if craft.session.isLoggedIn %}
        I'm logged in!
    {% else %}
        I should log in!
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah... that won't work.

Craft currently uses the URI segments to determine special path like logging in, out, etc.

So when Craft sees `account` as the first segment in the URI, its going to treat that as a login request and execute what's in `UsersController->actionLogin()`, which will see that you're already logged in, and will eventually hit this if the user doesn't have CP access permissions:

```
// Otherwise send them wherever postLoginRedirect tells us
$postLoginRedirect = craft()->config->get('postLoginRedirect');
$returnUrl = UrlHelper::getSiteUrl($postLoginRedirect);
```

Which, you've got set to `account`, then it rinses and repeats given you the infinite redirect loop.